# Redirect from URL with parameters to SEO friendly URL in .htaccess

Tags: seo, htaccess, php, mod-rewrite

I have category page with this structure

```
example.com/Category.php?Category_Id=10&Category_Title=some-text
```

i want to write htaccess rules to redirect from

```
example.com/Category.php?Category_Id=10&Category_Title=some-text
```

to this

```
example.com/Category/10/some-text
```

is there any way to force htaccess to do it. i want when i visit the

```
example.com/Category.php?Category_Id=10&Category_Title=some-text
```

the Category page automatically redirect to

```
example.com/Category/10/some-text
```

i use this htaccess code but it not redirect page to seo friendly url

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^exmaple\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://exmaple.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

how can i do it?

Comment: I assume that Category.php is still the actual file that is handling the category pages?   If so, where is your rewrite rule to it?

Comment: can you give me full htaccess rules to do this?

Comment: So which do you want?   Do you want the rules to redirect away from the parameters, or do you want the rules to implement the friendly URLs?

Comment: Just to confirm... have you already changed the URL in your application to the "pretty" format? eg. The URL the user sees on the page is `example.com/Category/10/some-text`, not `example.com/Category.php?Category_Id=10&Category_Title=some-text`?

Comment: yes .but it's a lot.a have to make all url's pretty in all page and i'am doing this now.but i want to know if there is a htaccess solution i do it.so you say changing url in all pages is the only solution...thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

```
# Redirect /Category.php?Category_Id=10&Category_Title=some-text
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Category_Id=(\d+)&Category_Title=([\w-]+)$
RewriteRule ^Category\.php$ /Category/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

---

> i changed generated link from bad seo structure to seo friendly structure and it works

Fair enough, glad you got it sorted, I assume you are using some kind of CMS? (This probably added *something* to your `.htaccess` I would think?)

Anyway, to address your initial question(s)...

> **Me:** have you already changed the URL in your application to the "pretty" format? eg. The URL the user sees on the page is `example.com/Category/10/some-text`, not `example.com/Category.php?Category_Id=10&Category_Title=some-‌text`?
>
> **You:** yes .but it's a lot.a have to make all url's pretty in all page and i'am doing this now.but i want to know if there is a htaccess solution i do it.so you say changing url in all pages is the only solution...

Whilst it's technically possible to implement this solely in `.htaccess`, without actually changing the URLs in your application, it's not recommended. It would deliver a bad user experience and would potentially be damaging to your site's SEO.

If you didn't change the URL in your application then every time a user clicked an internal link they would experience an external redirect (a second request) to the canonical URL (until the redirect was cached). That's an extra (unnecessary) request on your server. The old URL would be exposed to the user and copyable (eg. "Copy link address").

Ordinarily, the only reason to implement such a redirect is if the old URLs had already been linked to and/or search engines had already indexed the old URL structure. The redirect is then required in order to preserve SEO.

### Internal rewrite (new "pretty" URL to old "ugly" URL)

In order to implement a user-friendly URL structure like this, you would need an *internal rewrite* that silently rewrites the request from the new "pretty" URL back to the old "ugly" (real) URL. The user only sees the new "pretty" URL. It is assumed from your question that you already had something like this (maybe not)? For example:

```
# Rewrite /Category/10/some-text
RewriteRule ^Category/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ Category.php?Category_Id=$1&Category_Title=$2 [L]
```

`$1` and `$2` are backreferences to the captured groups in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. `\d+` and `[\w-]+` respectively.

If this was a new site then you could stop there, however...

### External redirect (old "ugly" URL to new "pretty" URL) - *optional*

This redirect should go *before* the above rewrite in your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect /Category.php?Category_Id=10&Category_Title=some-text
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Category_Id=(\d+)&Category_Title=([\w-]+)$
RewriteRule ^Category\.php$ /Category/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

In order to check the query string part of the URL you must use a `RewriteCond` directive and check against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable (the `RewriteRule` *pattern* only matches against the URL-path part of the URL).

`%1` and `%2` are backreferences to the captured groups in the last matched *CondPattern*. ie. `\d+` and `[\w-]+` respectively. This is the reverse of the earlier rewrite.

The `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` *substitution* is required to remove the query string from the request. (Alternatively you can use the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4+)

**UPDATE:** The *condition* that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that we only redirect the initial request and not the rewritten request by the later directive (see above). The `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var does not exist (ie. is empty) on the initial request and is only set after the first internal rewrite/subrequest. (In a per-directory context (like `.htaccess`), the rewriting process essentially starts over after the last `RewriteRule`, and continues to do so until the URL passes through unchanged. The `L` flag simply causes the "current pass" through the rewriting process to end, triggering the process to effectively start again, using the now rewritten URL as input.)

### Summary

Bringing this together, we have:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

# Canonical www to non-www redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://exmaple.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect /Category.php?Category_Id=10&Category_Title=some-text
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Category_Id=(\d+)&Category_Title=([\w-]+)$
RewriteRule ^Category\.php$ /Category/%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# Rewrite /Category/10/some-text
RewriteRule ^Category/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ Category.php?Category_Id=$1&Category_Title=$2 [L]
```

MultiViews will need to be disabled (if it's not already) for this particular example to work.

Comment: so helpfull...another thing..sorry for my english..i can't speak well...how ever thanks god you guys are here :)

Comment: Thanks. I had to add `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` to prevent both rules being somehow strangely mixed together (like if `L` was not being considered). (+1)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, thanks, missed that! That condition is required to prevent the _rewritten_ URL being redirected and causing a redirect loop. We only want to redirect the initial request. I've updated my answer and added a bit of explanation in that regard. (Also noticed a typo in the query string that had unfortunately propagated through copy/paste - fixed that.)

Answer (score -1):

I think something like this should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^Category.php?Category_Id=/(.*)$ /category/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^&Category_Title=/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: i changed generated link from bad seo structure to seo friendly structure and it works

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to have to downvote - there's no way this answer would get even close to "working" (regardless of the question). The first rule doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question (it looks like a _malformed_ HTTPS/HTTP redirect - but why?). The next two rules won't do anything either: you can't match the query string with the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. And the _substitution_ strings are also incorrect. But this is also (somehow) split across two directives?! Etc. etc.